# Trigger to update Account Primary Contact

Tags: trigger

I am trying to create a Trigger on Contact, which fires if a custom checkbox (Primary_Contact__c) is TRUE.

When the checkbox is TRUE, it should update a custom lookup field (also called Primary_Contact__c) on the related Account.

Additionally, only one contact should be a primary contact (Checkbox = TRUE).

Currently when checking the Primary_Contact__c on contact, nothing happens.

```
trigger primaryContact on Contact (after insert, after update) {

    Map<Id, Id> accountPrimaryContactMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
    Map<Id, Account> accountsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Account>();
    List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<contact>();

    FOR (Contact con : Trigger.new) {
        if(con.account != NULL){
            accountPrimaryContactMap.put(con.Accountid, con.id);
        }
    }

    FOR (Contact con : [SELECT id,name,Primary_Contact__c FROM Contact WHERE Accountid IN : accountPrimaryContactMap.keySet()]){
        if (trigger.newMap.get(con.Id).Primary_Contact__c && (!trigger.oldMap.get(con.Id).Primary_Contact__c && trigger.oldMap != null)) {
            if(con.Account.Primary_Contact__c != con.id){
                account a = new account(Primary_Contact__c = con.Id);
                accountsToUpdate.put(a.id,a);
            }
        }else{
            con.Primary_Contact__c = FALSE;
            contactsToUpdate.add(con);
        }
    }
    if (!accountsToUpdate.values().isEmpty()) {
        update accountsToUpdate.values();
    }
    if (!contactsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
        update contactsToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) you are going to have recursion issues as when you update the contacts; the trigger will fire again; (2) the tests for empty are unnecessary; DML on empty lists is a NOP

Answer (score 1):

You should do a few things differently to help layer your application:

```
//Logic-Less Trigger on Case
Trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update) {

ContactTriggerHandler handler = new ContactTriggerHandler();

if(Trigger.IsAfter && Trigger.IsInsert){
    handler.AfterInsert(Trigger.new, Trigger.newMap);
} else if(Trigger.IsAfter && Trigger.IsUpdate){
    handler.AfterUpdate(Trigger.old, trigger.oldMap, Trigger.new, trigger.newMap);
}

}


//Trigger Handler
public class ContactTriggerHandler{

public static void AfterInsert(List<Contact> newList, Map<Id,Contact> newMap){
    ContactTriggerHelper.HandlePrimaryContactOnAccount(newList);
}

public static void AfterUpdate(List<Contact> oldList, Map<Id,Contact> oldMap, List<Contact> newList, Map<Id,Contact> newMap){
    ContactTriggerHelper.HandlePrimaryContactOnAccount(newList);
}

}


//TriggerHelper - Does real Logic
public class ContactTriggerHelper{

public Static void HandlePrimaryContactOnAccount(List<Contact> contactList){
    Map<Id,Id> accountIDToPrimaryContactID = new Map<Id,Id>();
    for(Contact cont : contactList){
        if(cont.Primary_Contact__c == true && cont.AccountID != null){
            accountIDToPrimaryContactID.put(cont.AccountID, cont.Id);
        }
    }

    if(!accountIDToPrimaryContactID.keyset().IsEmpty()){
        List<Account> accountsWithPrimaryContact = [SELECT ID, Primary_Contact__c (Select ID FROM Contacts WHERE Primary_Contact__c = true) FROM Account WHERE Id in: accountIDToPrimaryContactID.keyset()];
        List<Account> AccountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        For(Account acc : accountsWithPrimaryContact){
            if(!Acc.Contacts.IsEmpty() && Acc.Contacts[0].id != accountsWithPrimaryContact.get(acc.id)){
                Throw New MyException (‘You cannot set contact with ID: ’+ accountsWithPrimaryContact.get(acc.id)+’ as the primary contact for Account with ID: ’++Acc.id+’ Because Contact with ID: ’+  Acc.Contacts[0].id+’ is already set as primary’);
            }
        else{
            AccountsToUpdate.add( new Account(Id=acc.id, Primary_Contact__c = accountsWithPrimaryContact.get(acc.id));
        }
    }
    if(!AccountsToUpdate.IsEmpty()){
        Update accountsToUpdate;
    }
}

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch! One question, why is the helper its own class? I thought the handler also held the logic?

Comment: I always like to keep the helper  or service layer separate from the trigger handler. Trigger kicks off the process, Handler controls order of execution and recursion prevention, and the service/helper layer just does static actions on records.

Comment: Also, I didn't test that code or run it at all - it's just an example of how I would solve the problem :)

Comment: Also, it's probable better to do this before update and insert. Then you could throw the exception when you find the account already has one and halt the execution much earlier.

Comment: Hey Mitch, thanks for posting this, however there are dozens of errors on all components. I am struggling to fix up even the syntax, to then test, and understand each components functions. Is there anyway you can tidy your solution up? Ta :)

Answer (score 0):

Your line should be as below
contactsToUpdate.add(con);

Comment: Thanks Suneel, well spotted. I have updated the post as the trigger isnt performing as desired, even with the typo fixed.